# ansible returns with "Failed to import the required Python library (Docker SDK for Python: docker (Python >= 2.7) or docker-py (Python 2.6))

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

I am running myserver in ubuntu:

```
+ sudo cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.6 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
VERSION_CODENAME=xenial
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial
```

I use ansible and when I run it I get the following error:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to import the required Python library (Docker SDK for Python: docker (Python >= 2.7) or docker-py (Python 2.6)) on dd63315fad06's Python /usr/bin/python. Please read module documentation and install in the appropriate location, for example via `pip install docker` or `pip install docker-py` (Python 2.6). The error was: No module named docker"}
```

when I run

```
python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"
```

I see:

```
['', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-19.2.2-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fasteners-0.15-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/monotonic-1.5-py2.7.egg', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
```

and python versions are as follows:

```
+ python --version
Python 2.7.12
+ python3 --version
Python 3.5.2
```

Then as I see everything is fine and I am not sure why I get

```
"Failed to import the required Python library (Docker SDK for Python: docker (Python >= 2.7) or docker-py (Python 2.6)) on dd63315fad06's Python /usr/bin/python. Please read module documentation and install in the appropriate location, for example via `pip install docker` or `pip install docker-py` (Python 2.6). The error was: No module named docker"
```

in ansible?

Comment: The error seems mostly self-explanatory. Have you installed the Docker module for Python?

Comment: @larsks oops after you pointed I noticed I was installing it with sudo pip3 install docker-py. I changed it to sudo pip2 install docker-py and worked Please add it as an answer and I will accept it this if anyone else face he can learn from it.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It appears that you don't have the `docker` module installed.

You will need to install it via your system package manager (`apt install python-docker`, for example), or using `pip` (`pip install docker`).

If you have multiple Python versions, make sure that you've installed the `docker` module into the version that Ansible is using.

Comment: Also if the package is installed on a user level, the installed package might not be visible to the ansible user

Answer (score 16):

Here, in May 2021 for Ubuntu 20.04 you need to run `apt install python3-docker` because no python 2.x is shipped by default anymore

Answer (score 11):

I have faced the same issue for the Ansible docker-compose module. I was able to fix it by selecting python3 for those tasks.

## Before (Not working)

```
- name: Create docker service services
  docker_compose:
    project_src: /root/
  become: true
```

## After (Working)

We can get the python location by **$which python3**

```
- name: Create fleuntd services
  docker_compose:
    project_src: /root/
  become: true
  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: /bin/python3
```

Comment: On Ubuntu you can install proper package: `apt install python-is-python3`

Answer (score 4):

I started getting this same error in April 2021, with the release of Version 5.0 of the Docker SDK For Python.   The error message was almost the exact same as the original question, with the only difference being that at the end of the error message was one of the statements:

`The error was: No module named parse`

or

`The error was: No module named selectors`

This was ultimately due to the older version of `pip` that Ansible was using, incorrectly installing a Python3 library on a Python2.7 setup.   The fix was to pin the version of the `docker` Python library to something earlier than Version 5.0, and the 'websocket-client' library to something earlier than Version 1.0:

```
- name: Install Docker SDK for Python
  pip:
    name: "docker<5" 
  become: yes

- name: Setup more docker dependencies
  pip:
    name: "websocket-client<1" 
  become: yes
```

Alternatively, this set of commands would have also worked, given that Python2 was still in use:

```
pip install docker<5
pip install websocket-client<1
```

Once these older versions of the Docker SDK for Python and Websocket Client were installed, Ansible was able to again successfully manage Docker on my behalf.

Answer (score 3):

In my case (Ubuntu 20 with installed docker) these commands was required

```
apt update
apt install python3 python3-pip
pip3 install docker docker-compose
```

Detailed requirements:

> https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/docker_compose_module.html

Comment: this solution stopped works today

Answer (score 0):

Debian bootstrap with debian 10 have native python 2.6 enter to eco with chroot and install ansible it's easy

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).