# Build and deploy with Gitlab CI?

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab

I have a Dockerized Angular/Node.js app that I'm trying to deploy via GitLab CI.

Using GitLab CI, I build and push the images to the GitLab container registry using a dedicated build VM/server with a Runner on it, and then the images should be pulled and started as containers in another server, i.e. the production server.

This is what my `gitlab-ci.yml` file looks like right now:

```
image: docker:latest

#services:
#    - docker:dind

stages:
    - build
    - deploy

build-1:
    stage: build
    only:
        - deploy
    script:
        - docker login -u $GITLAB_USERNAME -p $CI_ACCESS_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
        - docker build -t $FRONTEND_IMG .
        - echo Pushing Docker image to GitLab
        - docker push $FRONTEND_IMG
    when: manual
    tags:
        - my-runner

build-2:
  stage: build
  only:
    - deploy
  script:
    - docker login -u $GITLAB_USERNAME -p $CI_ACCESS_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker build -t $BACKEND_IMG .
    - docker push $BACKEND_IMG
  when: manual
  tags:
    - my-runner

deploy-live:
    stage: deploy
    only:
        - deploy
    before_script:
        ## Install ssh-agent if not already installed, it is required by Docker.
        ## (change apt-get to yum if you use an RPM-based image)
        ##
        - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'

        ##
        ## Run ssh-agent (inside the build environment)
        ##
        - eval $(ssh-agent -s)

        ##
        ## Add the SSH key stored in SSH_PRIVATE_KEY variable to the agent store
        ## We're using tr to fix line endings which makes ed25519 keys work
        ## without extra base64 encoding.
        ## https://gitlab.com/gitlab-examples/ssh-private-key/issues/1#note_48526556
        ##
        - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add -

        ##
        ## Create the SSH directory and give it the right permissions
        ##
        - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
        - chmod 700 ~/.ssh

        # - mkdir -p ~/.ssh && touch ~/.ssh/known_hosts
        # - echo "$SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS" >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
        ##
        ## Use ssh-keyscan to scan the keys of your private server. Replace gitlab.com
        ## with your own domain name. You can copy and repeat that command if you have
        ## more than one server to connect to.
        ##
        - ssh-keyscan $SERVER_IP_ADDRESS >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
        - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    script:
        - echo SSH to prod server
        - ssh $SERVER_USERNAME@$SERVER_IP_ADDRESS && ip addr show && docker login -u $GITLAB_USERNAME -p $CI_ACCESS_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY && docker pull $FRONTEND_IMG && docker pull $BACKEND_IMG && docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d
    when: manual
    tags:
        - my-runner
```

- The problem is, the docker commands seem to get executed on the build server (instead of the production server where we `ssh`) and the app is accessible from there but not from the production server.
- When I run `docker images` on the production server after the deployment, the list comes up empty. But when I do that in the build server, the images that were built are there.
- The job seems to complete successfully with no error messages, but I do get these messages:

`Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.`

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-66-generic x86_64)
  * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
  * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
  * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage
   System information as of Wed Apr 15 00:58:45 UTC 2020
   System load:  0.0               Processes:              110
   Usage of /:   6.0% of 24.06GB   Users logged in:        2
   Memory usage: 26%               IP address for eth0:    x.x.x.x
   Swap usage:   0%                IP address for docker0: x.x.x.x
 121 packages can be updated.
 73 updates are security updates.
 mesg: ttyname failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: `ssh myserver && do_something` will connect with ssh then do_something on current host (when ssh exist). `ssh myserver do_something && otherthing` wiill execute do_something via ssh and otherthing on current host. To run your full set of commands over ssh you have to quote the full command => `ssh myserver "command1 && command2 &&....."`

Comment: @Zeitounator hi, thanks for this, it helped. But now I think I need to figure out how to use `docker-compose` if my approach is gonna be this. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

after taking a look at your ci code, you should use **ansible** when you want to run your container on the production server.

Ansible is better than

```sh
ssh myserver "command1 && command2 &&....."
```

Answer (score 1):

I can share with you my ansible file `deploy.yml`

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59384708/ansible-returns-with-failed-to-import-the-required-python-library-docker-sdk-f/65495769#65495769
---
- name: Build
  hosts: local
  connection: local
  tags:
    - build
  tasks:
    - name: Build Image
      community.general.docker_image:
        build:
          path: .
          pull: no
        name: registry.digitalocean.com/main/example-com
        push: true
        source: build
        force_source: yes
      environment:
        DOCKER_BUILDKIT: 1
- name: Deploy
  hosts: remote
  tags:
    - deploy
  vars:
    path: /root/example.com
  tasks:
    - name: Creates directory
      file:
        path: "{{ path }}"
        state: directory
    - name: Copy Docker Compose
      copy:
        src: docker-compose.yml
        dest: "{{ path }}/docker-compose.yml"
    - name: Reload Compose
      community.general.docker_compose:
        pull: yes
        project_src: "{{ path }}"
```

And gitlab ci file `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
variables:
  DOCKER_REGISTRY_DOMAIN: "registry.digitalocean.com"
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2

image: docker:latest

services:
  - docker:dind

.deploy:
  image: archlinux:latest
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
    - pacman -Sy make ansible python python-pip openssh docker --noconfirm
    - docker login -u ${DOCKER_TOKEN} -p ${DOCKER_TOKEN} ${DOCKER_REGISTRY_DOMAIN}
    - pip3 install docker docker-compose
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - ssh-add <(echo $SSH_PRIVATE_KEY_BASE64 | base64 -d)
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'
  script:
    - ansible-playbook -i hosts deploy.yml

deploy:
  extends: .deploy
  environment:
    name: production
    url: https://example.com
  only:
    refs:
      - prod
```

Finally `hosts`

```
[local]
127.0.0.1 env=prod

[remote]
xxx.xxx.xxx ansible_user=root env=prod
```

Like `fei yang` I too recommend replace `ssh` command by `ansible`.

---

I think that problem can be there:

```
ssh $SERVER_USERNAME@$SERVER_IP_ADDRESS && ip addr show
```

In my computer I can run:

```
curl ipinfo.io
```

and get:

```
{
  "ip": "193.118.225.242"
...
```

Then I typed:

```
ssh root@104.248.40.145 && curl ipinfo.io
```

I see:

```
Last login: Thu Jun 17 07:53:38 2021 from 193.118.225.242
```

I am logged in to server and I can't see resutls of `ipinfo`

When I typed

```
exit
```

to logout from remote server I can see:

```
logout
Connection to 104.248.40.145 closed.
{
  "ip": "193.118.225.242",
```

To execute command remotelly by ssh you should not use `&&` but `""` eg.

```
ssh root@104.248.40.145 "curl ipinfo.io"
```